# react-navigation: nested navigators navigation routes with redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a tab navigator nested inside a stack navigator with Redux, with the following structure:

- Stack Nav:

  - Tab Nav
  - Add Program Screen
- Tab Nav

  - Main Screen

What I'm trying to achieve is navigating to Add Program Screen within Main Screen, Shouldn't the Tab Nav have access to the two routes defined in Stack Nav?

While I the only route I see is the Tab Nav, My code is the following:

```
export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Main: {screen: tabWithNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Home'},
    AddProgram: { 
        screen: AddProgramScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            title: 'Add Program'
         }) 
        },
    }
});

class AppWithNavigationState extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { dispatch, nav } = this.props;
        return (
            <AppNavigator
                navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
                    dispatch,
                    state: nav,
                    addListener,
                })}
            />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    nav: state.stackNav
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithNavigationState);
```

tabWithNavigator implemented almost identically just with TabNavigator instead of StackNavigator.
When I console.log the this.props.navigation inside the Object at Tab Nav component there is only:

```
"state": Object {
  "key": "id-1324343445-2",
  "routeName": "Main",
}
```

Am I missing something?